# In a Mac Catalyst app, how do I set the draggable zone to move the window around the screen?

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst

I have a custom "header" in my app, with an hidden titlebar.

How do I set the header (a simple UIView) as the handle zone to move the window?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had a custom `UINavigationController` and I needed to override `touchesBegan` but it should be easy to adopt the following code in your case.

We get the `NSWindow` object which is not directly available in Mac Catalyst and then perform the drag event when our navbar receives a touch. You can use this on any other view, it doesn't need to be an `UINavigation` item.

```
public extension UIResponder {
    
    func performMacCatalystWindowDrag() {
        #if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
        guard let nsApp = ((NSClassFromString("NSApplication") as? NSObject.Type)?.value(forKey: "sharedApplication") as? NSObject),
            let currentEvent = nsApp.value(forKey: "currentEvent") as? NSObject,
            let nsWindow = currentEvent.value(forKey: "window") as? NSObject else { return }
        nsWindow.perform(NSSelectorFromString("performWindowDragWithEvent:"), with: currentEvent)
        #endif
    }
}
```

And in your custom navigation bar override `touchesBegan`

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    performMacCatalystWindowDrag()
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
}
```

The above code doesn't belong to me, click [here](https://gist.github.com/JunyuKuang/9295390c9b7b5bef89d9f956f524836a) to see more.

Comment: Leaving the app in the background for a while seems to cause a crash with *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'

Would you know if there is any way to fix this?